# Creating a sequence for a column's value with minimum value 1 if no values exist, and 1 larger than the highest value on the column if values exist

Tags: java, sql, jpa, sql-server-2012, sequence

I have the table `organisation` and it has a column `customer_number`.

Now, I'm supposed to create a sequence, where whenever a new `organisation` is created - as in a new row is persisted to the table - the `customer_number`column on the new row would get value 1 IF no values exist in the column `customer_number` on any row. IF values DO exist, the new row would get a value on said column, which would be the highest value on said column in the table plus one.

**Example:** If there would be no rows or only rows that have no value on `customer_number` column, the newly added `organisation` row would get 1 as the value for its customer_number column. If there would be already for example two rows with values on said column - say 100 and 200 - the new row would get value 201 on that column.

I just can't figure out the SQL spells to achieve this goal.

The database is SQL Server 2012.

I already have a sequence for IDs. Here's how it is in the SQL-script that creates the table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE organisation_seq AS BIGINT START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
CREATE TABLE organisation
(
  id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  customer_number VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
... rest of the columns ...
);
```

In the Organisation Entity bean it is like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "organisation")
public class Organisation {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Organisation.class.getName());
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="organisationSeq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="organisationSeq", sequenceName="organisation_seq", allocationSize=1)
    private Long id;

    private String customerNumber;

   ... rest of the Entity properties ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to be able to restart a sequence starting at a value determined by a query, you can do that with dynamic sql like so:

```
create procedure dbo.mysequence_restart as 
begin
set nocount, xact_abort on;
  declare @restartSequence nvarchar(256);
  declare @restartWith nvarchar(10); = convert(nvarchar(10),isnull((
    select max(id)+1 
    from organisation 
    where customer_number is not null
    ), 1));

  set @restartSequence = 'alter sequence dbo.mysequence restart with '+@restartWith+';'; 
  exec sp_executesql @restartSequence;
end;
go
```

This does not have to be in a procedure, it is just an example.

---

That is not exactly how a `sequence` works in Sql Server. Here is a quick comparison of how a `sequence` and `identity` react to inserted values they did not generate.

Test setup: http://rextester.com/VDDF36095

```
/* ------------- using sequence ----------- */
create sequence organisation_seq as bigint 
  start with 1 increment by 1;
create table organisation
(
  id bigint not null default next value for organisation_seq,
  customer_number varchar(50) unique
);

insert into organisation values
 (next value for organisation_seq, 'a')
,(200, 'b')
,(next value for organisation_seq, 'c');

select * from organisation;
```

returns:

```
+-----+-----------------+
| id  | customer_number |
+-----+-----------------+
|   1 | a               |
| 200 | b               |
|   2 | c               |
+-----+-----------------+
```

---

If you use `identity` instead:

```
/* ------------- using identity ----------- */
create table organisation_identity
(
  id bigint not null identity (1,1),
  customer_number varchar(50) unique
);

insert into organisation_identity values
('a');

/* ------------- identity_insert on ----------- */
set identity_insert organisation_identity on;
insert into organisation_identity (id, customer_number) values
(200, 'b');
set identity_insert organisation_identity off;
/* ------------- identity_insert off ----------- */

insert into organisation_identity values
('c');

select * from organisation_identity;
```

returns:

```
+-----+-----------------+
| id  | customer_number |
+-----+-----------------+
|   1 | a               |
| 200 | b               |
| 201 | c               |
+-----+-----------------+
```

---

Sequence Reference:

- [Sequence Numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx)
- [`create sequence`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx)
- [`next value for`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx)
- [`sp_sequence_get_range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878352.aspx)
- [Simple Talk - Sql Server sequence basics - Joe Celko](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-sequence-basics/)

Identity Reference:

- [`identity()` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)
- [`identity()` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx)
- [`scope_identity()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)
- [`set identity_insert` - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

Comment: Great and thorough answer but that doesn't solve the problem. I need to alter the customer_number column. I think you can't alter table and add auto-incrementation by IDENTITY on it.

Comment: @SteveWaters Updated with another alternative.